# Meta description is not updating in old products - Magento ver. 1.9.3.2

Tags: magento-1.9, meta-description

I'm trying to update meta description from the backend but when I save it... it got blank again.
I tried to import meta tags through excel sheet. But again I found the description text area blank.

Please help me out ASAP

Comment: What you have done , have you installed any extension ?? or done some code ??

Answer (score 1):

- Remove old log files from **`{document-root}/var/log`** folder. Try to save the meta description again from the backend. When the blank page appears, check the **`{document-root}/var/log`** folder for errors.
- If nothing found in the {document-root}/var/log folder, open index.php file in the document root and try to save the product again. This time, you should have the error details on the screen instead of the blank screen.
- You can also check server logs under **`/var/log/{apache2|httpd}/error.log`**

**Note:** you need to specify only one between apache2 or httpd.

**Note:** The location of error log can be different in case you have multiple virtual hosts configured on the same server or you have nginx instead of apache server.

Comment: No, 
It's not working..

Comment: The problem is happening only with old products, not with new products.
Why so???

Comment: When you follow above steps, what are you getting?